# Ad hoc vs Mesh, which one to use?

Tags: routing, wireless, ieee-802.11, networking, ad-hoc-wireless

Say we have four nodes (A, B, C, D) that are arranged in a chain-like topology.

```
A <-------> B <-------> C <-------> D
```

Only the adjacent nodes are in range of one another (A can communicate with B, B can do so with A and C, C can do so with B and D, and D only with C). Is it possible to create an 802.11 ad hoc network (an IBSS) in such a case? After going through the requirements for an IBSS in the 802.11 standard, it seems that all four nodes would have to be in range of one another. Why is this so? My guess is that for exchanging beacons, all the nodes would have to be in range of one another.

Alternatively, can the above topology be achieved through an 802.11 mesh network? For instance, B and C could act as gateways ('mesh routers' might be the more accurate term) for communication between A and D.

Assume that a single/same channel is used for communication between all nodes.

Comment: Ad hoc assumes all stations can hear each other, so it wouldn’t work in this case.